# how to send array with URL from objective c to php without using xml or json?

Tags: objective-c

With PHP is using the serialize and unserialize function but, how to serialize in objective c for send to URL? Or some idea?

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is great for transmitting data objects over HTTP in a language-independent manner, and there are JSON parsing libraries available for both Objective-C and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), it's easy to use.